# Webdriverio: selecting an option from options picker in React Native app

Tags: react-native, appium, webdriver-io

I'm writing an "enroll" BDD test for an ios react native app using webdriver and appium. When the user inputs their shipping information, we have an options-picker for inputting their state. The action they are to take is: **click the field that inputs their home state then scroll down to their home state**

I'm trying to select "NY" for the test. I've tried the following (from the appium docs):

```
$("~element").click();
$("~element").sendKeys("NY")
```

and I tried

```
$("~element").touchAction({})
```

from webdriverio docs.

Has anyone ever figured out a way to do this?

Comment: could you add the html

Comment: is it a select tag ?

Comment: can't you click and wait then wait for dropdown and then click the visible list ? https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/selectByIndex